# Extracting time from a date/time format

Tags: r

So I have a variable which measures the time that an entry was logged into the database, currently the form of these entries is:

```
"2018-09-22T14:00:09Z"
"2018-09-26T08:21:16Z"
```

Basically I need to extract from these strings only the time section of the entry. So the 8 characters between T and Z. By the way it is always letters T and Z that surround the time.

I would also like to store these times in a new variable called "times" and this be of a time class.

Is this at all possible in R??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One base R option uses `sub`:

```
ts <- c("2018-09-22T14:00:09Z", "2018-09-26T08:21:16Z")
out <- sub("^.*T(.*)Z$", "\\1", ts)

[1] "14:00:09" "08:21:16"
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with a simplified version.

Comment: @SeamusO'Leary you replace `ts` with `x` for every case.