# Determining response time in R

Tags: r

I have a running list of 2 variables which include a date and time component. The form of these variables are:

```
2015-08-29T11:52:04
2015-08-29T11:52:19
```

I would like to extract the time sections from the variables above (i.e. everything after 'T') and calculate the difference to determine a response time (i.e. 15 seconds in this case)

Looking for some guidance on how to approach this with R. I found a similar solution ([Extracting time from a date/time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043595/extracting-time-from-a-date-time-format)) but am having difficulty applying the solution to my problem here.

Would appreciate any guidance! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, we can convert the time to `POSIXct` class and use `difftime` to calculate difference between the two specifying `units` as required.

```
time1 <- '2015-08-29T11:52:04'
time2 <- '2015-08-29T11:52:19'

as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(time2, format = '%FT%T'), 
                    as.POSIXct(time1, format = '%FT%T'), units = 'secs'))
#[1] 15
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! very helpful

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to `ITime` and calculate the difference.  Based on the OP's post, we need to remove the prefix 'Date' up to 'T' and then use only the time part for calculating the difference

```
library(data.table)
diff(as.ITime(sub('.*T', '', str1)))
#[1] "00:00:15"
```

Or another option is to convert the full string to `DateTime` with `ymd_hms`, convert to `ITime` and get the `diff`erence

```
diff(as.ITime(ymd_hms(str1)))
#[1] "00:00:15"
```

---

Or with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
as.numeric(diff(ymd_hms(str1)))
#[1] 15
```

---

Or with `difftime` in `base R` after converting to Datetime class with `as.POSIXct`

```
dtime <- as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%T")
as.numeric(difftime(dtime[2], dtime[1], unit = 'sec'))
#[1] 15
```

Or as @Onyambu suggested

```
diff(strptime(str1,"%FT%T"))
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("2015-08-29T11:52:04", "2015-08-29T11:52:19")
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response, much appreciated and helpful!

Comment: `diff(strptime(str1,"%FT%T"))` another base R solution